# Javascript - Array with Split function

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have trouble to put information in a array with Javascript and Split.

```
var LigneTab= new Array(3,7); //4 Lines, 7 Items
var reg=new RegExp(" +", "g");

Ligne = ("55062 5453457.4676 236746.6682 472.4027 POA 2012-08-14 GM33P086"); //First Line
LigneTab[0]=Ligne.split(reg); //Split the line in 7 items and place it in line 0
UltraEdit.messageBox(LigneTab[0,4]]); // Debug msgbox from UltraEdit to show the item 4 'POA'
```

Comment: `new Array(3, 7)` creates an array with the values `[3, 7]`. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: in javascript, arrays are dinamic, so you dont have to set the size before.

Comment: Just because JavaScript *looks* like C# or Java doesn't mean that you can use identical syntax. `LigneTab[0,4]` is invalid, and should probably be `LigneTab[0][4]`.

Comment: oh! ok, i fix that : UltraEdit.messageBox(LigneTab[0],[4]);

Comment: `new Array(3,7)` does *not* make an array with `4 Lines, 7 Items`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the code you posted, I don't see why you need a two-dimensional array. But if you really need one, you are trying here is one of the possible ways to create it and access it:

```
var LigneTab = []; // one-dimensional for now
var reg=new RegExp(" +", "g");
var Ligne = "55062 5453457.4676 236746.6682 472.4027 POA 2012-08-14 GM33P086"; 
LigneTab[0] = Ligne.split(reg); 
// Now LigneTab is two-dimensional. 
// LigneTab[0] contains another array with 7 items
UltraEdit.messageBox(LigneTab[0][4]]);
```

Comment: Thats what i want; Sorry i don't figure this : For example i want to put the second line :     var Ligne = ("55062 5453457.4676 236746.6682 472.4027 POA 2012-08-14 GM33P086");
     var Ligne2 = ("55074 5453526.0731 236758.7675 478.6960 POA 2012-08-14 GM33P086");
    LigneTab[0] = Ligne.split(reg); 
    LigneTab[1] = Ligne2.split(reg)

Comment: That should work just fine. Also, note the last line of my example code, it shows the proper way to read from a multidimensional array

Comment: -WildcatQuebec Edit : Thats right; i need a dimension to put a Line and the second dimension is to put the 7 items :) Thx alot

Answer (score 1):

In javascript this doesn't have to be that complex:

```
var Ligne = "55062 5453457.4676 236746.6682 472.4027 POA 2012-08-14 GM33P086"
   ,LigneTab = [Ligne.split(/\s+/)];
   // now LigneTab[0] is:
   // ["55062", "5453457.4676", "236746.6682", "472.4027", ..., "GM33P086"]
```

Or even:

```
var Ligne = "55062 5453457.4676 236746.6682 472.4027 POA 2012-08-14 GM33P086"
             .split(/\s+/);
// Ligne[0]:
// ["55062", "5453457.4676", "236746.6682", "472.4027", ..., "GM33P086"]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you initialize the array as `[3, 7]`, and then you replace the zeroth value with the array you actually want, nested:

```
LigneTab[0]=Ligne.split(reg); //Split the line in 7 items and place it in line 0
```

So `LigneTab` is actually `[["55062","5453457.4676","236746.6682","472.4027","POA","2012-08-14","GM33P086"], 7]` and there is no value at index 4.

Second, if it did have > 4 elements, `LigneTab[0,4]` wouldn't make much sense, since the expression

```
0, 4
```

evaluates to `4`, so you might as well just write `LigneTab[4]`.

You probably want this:

```
var LigneTab = Ligne.split(/\s+/);
UltraEdit.messageBox(LigneTab[4]]); // Debug msgbox from UltraEdit to show the item 4 'POA'
```

Or, perhaps you intended to have it as a nested list, in which case you want:

```
var LigneTab[0] = Ligne.split(/\s+/);
UltraEdit.messageBox(LigneTab[0][4]);
```

Comment: Ligne = ("55062 5453457.4676 236746.6682 472.4027 POA 2012-08-14 GM33P086");
Ligne2= ("55074 5453526.0731 236758.7675 478.6960 POA 2012-08-14 GM33P086");
var reg=new RegExp(" +", "g");
LigneTab[0]=Ligne.split(reg);
LigneTab[1]=Ligne2.split(reg);
UltraEdit.messageBox(LigneTab[0],[4]); // Show the LigneTab[0] Item 4 POA